# A way to insert a # in front of a variable of the html attribute value data-bs-target

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

So basically, I have a vue web app and created a container with multiple bootstrap cards. The cards have a button, which collapses a form I've made for guests to apply. However, when I press the button of a card, it collapses the apply form of all cards at once. To fix that, I have to give each individual card a specific `id` which matches the `data-bs-target` and `aria-controls` of the button. So far, so good.

I've made a variable `card_id` and inserted it into the attribute values with `v-bind`, but it's not working. The reason is, that the attribute `data-bs-target` needs a hashtag before the actual variable name, but I can't figure out a way to do that.

Code sample:

```
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" :data-bs-target="card_id" aria-expanded="false" :aria-controls="card_id">Apply now!</button>
<div class="collapse" :id="card_id">
    <div class="card card-body">
      <GuestForm></GuestForm>
    </div>
</div>
```

I obviously can't just put a hashtag in front of the variable, so what is my next best solution for this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the string template with backticks `` like:

```html
  <button :data-bs-target="`#${card_id}`"
```